# Change the style class of an <img> with AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I've managed to get AJAX working so that PHP is executed on click of an image, however, I want this result to be shown visually in real time without the page reloading so I'd like to change the class of my `<img>` tags on click.

My image tag is currently something like `<img title="<?=$game['name']?>" class="game_<?=$complete?>" src="<?=$gameimgurl?>">` and I'd like to change it onclick with PHP/AJAX.

Is this possible? Thanks! :D

EDIT: I've fixed it thanks to your answers with this line: `document.getElementById(var1).className = "game_"+var2;`

However, this only works once as var2 is provided by PHP on the page and this remains the same - is there any way I can make it revert to the original/previous class on a second click so it works infinitely?

I'm only guessing here but is there any way for JS to get the current class and perhaps have some sort of "if" statement to change it to the opposite?

Comment: Yes, in the success method of your AJAX, target the img and change the class.

Comment: PHP runs on the server and has nothing to do with client-side styling or events. You don't need AJAX for this at all.

Comment: PHP is server side scripting language !! Simple javascript is what you are looking for.

Comment: Please post the HTML output of the PHP. Since AJAX uses JS that runs in the browser, we need to see what the browser gets from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the purpose of yours is only change the css class name you don't need AJAX call. You can do directly using javascript or jquery (if you are using jquery)

**Javascript**

To add/change class for an element:

```
document.getElementById("idMyElement").className = "MyCssClass";
```

To add additional class to an element:

`document.getElementById("idMyElement").className += " MyCssClass";` [NOTE: a space is added before MyCssClass]

To remove a class from an element:

```
document.getElementById("idMyElement").className =  document.getElementById("idMyElement").className.replace
      ( /(?:^|\s)MyCssClass(?!\S)/g , '' );
```

If you want to do with Jquery use as suggested by @Harshal Mahajan

If you need to change after AJAX call, you can use the above in the response of the AJAX call.

Comment: Brilliant, that did it. :)

Comment: Is there any way so I can force it to change back to the previous class if its clicked again in the same page load?

Comment: Sorry, should probably clarify - currently on click it knows to change it to the opposite class based on info provided by PHP on the page, so the info remains the same after the first class change.

Comment: I think we can use condition to check and revert back to old css class

if(document.getElementById("idMyElement").className == "MyCssClass") {
  document.getElementById("idMyElement").className = "oldMyCssClass";
}

Answer (score 3):

You can set the class by using [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), like this:

```
$("#idname").attr('class', 'newClass');
```

If you want to add a class, use [.addclass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) instead, like this:

```
$("#idname").addClass('newClass');
```

You can also remove the class using [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

```
$("#idname").removeClass('newClass');
```

Comment: Hi @Harshal Mahajan..Make js fiddle..its more useful upcoming user

Comment: @VIVEK-MDU Why would you need a JS fiddle? Just press `F12` to access developer tools and try the code out right there on this page.

Comment: @VIVEK-MDU...no issues.its much simple

Comment: How would I put this into my existing JS? I get an error saying that $ is not a function. (I'm not too familiar with JS/AJAX)

Comment: you need to include the js in your file, it is is not recognized the jqery code until you include the js.

Comment: I've put it in my JS file next to the function that calls the PHP file. It's giving me the same error in the console.

Comment: Show us your js and html Code.

Comment: Managed to get it working - however, it only works once - I've updated my original question! Thanks :)